# Java outputstream, trigger file download before all data retrieved from db

Tags: java, apache-poi, inputstream, httpresponse, fileoutputstream

Im trying to wrap my head around Java Out/Inputstreams, closing and flushing. I have a situation where I want to create a file using Apache POI with data from a server. I would like the file to start downloading as soon as I retrieve the first record from the DB(Show the file at the bottom of the browser has started to download).

```
public void createExcelFile(final HttpServletResponse response,
  final Long vendorId) {
    try {
      // setup responses types...

      final XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
      final XSSFSheet sheet = xssfWorkbook.createSheet("sheets1");

      // create file with data
      writeExcelOutputData(sheet, xssfWorkbook);

      xssfWorkbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
      xssfWorkbook.close();
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error("Boom");
    }
```

The above code will perform a file download no problem, but this could be a big file. I go off getting the data(around 20/30s) and then after that the download begins < no good...

Can I achive what I need or whats the best approach, thanks in advance

Cheers :)

Comment: You are trying to stream an excel file? Unless it is a stream you can't send it before it is finished.

Comment: And IF you make it in a stream you will not be able to download it. The client side browser will have to interpret it with some plugin.

Comment: I'll be returning the data in batches...so triggering the file to start downloading before all batches are revived is impossible???

Comment: There is no such thing in batches for a file download. Either it is a file or it is a stream. If it is a file it should be complete before you send it. What I recommend is to run the file generation in a thread, answer the user that the file is being processed, after it is done you send an email or a system notification to the user so He can download it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasons could be as following:

1. maybe there is a read/write timeout with your http server, then if the process gets lengthy or becasue of low-bandwidth, so the connection will be closed by the server.
2. make sure the process(the excel work) gets completely done, maybe there would be an error/exception during work.

The solution of Jorge looks very promising. User need once request for a file, then server would do the work in background and then either user check the work process and download the file if ready, or server informs the user by email, web notification, etc...

Also you would keep the file in the server in a temp file for a while, and if the connection gets interrupted, server would respond the generated file partial(omit the bytes sent, like normal file download)

Keeping a connection alive to do a lengthy work is not very logical.

Again, if the file gets ready fast(really fast) for download/stream, and the download interrupts, if could be becasue of read/write timeout by server, or a very bad network.